# FQL Procurando amigos pelo escola de graduação

Tags: facebook

Como eu poderia localizar novos amigos utilizando FQL Query, utilizando como filtro a o nome da escola de graduação?

Não funciona:

```
select uid, name from user where education.school.name = "Universidade de São Paulo"
```

porque tem que usar um campo indexado, como código ou fazer uma subquery com amigos que são meus amigos.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @Araponga Brots achou alguma solução?